# Como pegar o valor do value e também do name do checkbox na mesma hora que selecionar jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Preciso pegar o `name` dos *checkbox* selecionados assim que eu clicar num dos *checkbox* que existem na página. O `value` eu já consegui, porém preciso pegar também o valor do `name`.

Algué poderia me ajudar ou me dar outra alternativa pois preciso pegar o valor do `name` e `value` ao mesmo tempo que clicar.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  
 $('input[name="1117"]').click(function () { 
  selecionado('1117'); 
 }); 
 var selecionado = function (grupo) { 
  var result = $('input[name="' + grupo + '"]:checked'); 
  if (result.length > 0) { 
   var contador = result.length + " selecionado(s)<br/>"; 
   result.each(function () { 
    contador += $(this).val() + " "
   }); 
   $('#divFiltros').html(contador); 
  } 
  else { 
   $('#divFiltros').html("Nenhum selecionado"); 
  } 
 }; 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="divFiltros"></div>

<form method="POST"> 
      
      <legend>Marca</legend>
      
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="6327" name="1117" value="6327">
           <label for="">Samsung</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="6327" name="1117" value="6328">
           <label for="">Motorola</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="6327" name="1117" value="6329">
           <label for="">Sony</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="6327" name="1117" value="6330">
           <label for="">LG</label>
      </div>
      
      <legend>Especificação</legend>
      
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="450" name="1120" value="450">
           <label for="450">4G</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="455" name="1120" value="455">
           <label for="455">2 Chips</label>
      </div>
      <div class="checkbox checkbox-success">
           <input class="styled marca" type="checkbox" id="461" name="1120" value="461">
           <label for="461">Video 4K</label>
      </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Já experimentaste com `this.name` dentro do event handler?

Comment: ainda não...como seria? Nçao sei muito de Jquery, apenas um pouco de php

Comment: De que maneira precisas de usar o `name`?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: https://jsfiddle.net/0y8heu9r/

Comment: Quase isso...=) Preciso que mostre todas ao mesmo tempo, pois quando clicamos em Especificações some a Marca.... teria como mostrar tudo junto?

Comment: tipo mesclado mostrar a Marca e a Especificação na #divFiltros

Comment: Então não precisas do `name`, queres is buscar todos os inputs marcados independentemente do `name`, é isso?

Comment: preciso dos 2 pois preciso usar os 2 name e value para buscar os produtos de acordo com o código da especificações e da especificação própriamente dita.

Comment: EX: Marca id: 1117 Sansung id:6327, LG id:6328...

Comment: Especificação id: 1120 - 4g id:450, 2chips id:455...

Comment: Ok, algo assim então: https://jsfiddle.net/0y8heu9r/1/ ?

Comment: ISSOOOOO....SHOWWW

Comment: MUITOOO BOM....

Comment: Muito obrigado Sergio isso mesmo que eu precisava, Deus Abençoe!!!

Comment: De nada, vou dar uma resposta para ficar mais completo.

Answer (score 1):

O name é uma propriedade do objeto. É também um atributo do elemento que esse objeto representa.

Isso quer dizer que podes ir buscar esse valor com `.name` ou com `getAttribute('name');`.

Assim se o que procuras é saber quais os items foram selecionados podes usar:

```
var escolhidos = $('input:checked');
```

para saber quais os `checkbox` marcados, e depois mapear essa array só com o que interessa: o `name` e o `value`.

```
var escolhidos = $('input:checked');
var selecionados = escolhidos.map(function() {
     var produto = {nome: this.name, value: this.value};
     return produto;
}).get(); // o .get() é para discartar o jquery e trabalhar só com uma array nativa
```

#### exemplo: https://jsfiddle.net/3nexkLnn/

Comment: Olá Sergio, como eu poderia fazer a soma dos `values` dos inputs nesse jsfiddle?